# How to verify wp user password by sql query in wp?

Tags: posts, wp-query, users, sql, password

I want to verify the user password without function only by the SQL query.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information. What do you want to achieve? Will this function be inside the wordpress environment (will you have access to the wordpress functions)?